# FullCalendar 3.8 keep looping when set minTime and maxTime in EventAfterAllRender

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have problem with my implementation of FullCalendar. My calendar keeps looping when I tried to set minTime and maxTime in EventAfterAllRender.

```
        (function(c) {
            var calendarOptions = {
                schedulerLicenseKey: '',
                header             : {
                    left  : 'prevYear,prev today next,nextYear',
                    center: 'title',
                    right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events             : {
                    url : '{{ url("calendar/events-json-calendar") }}',
                    data: function () {
                        return {
                            id         : $('#calendarsselect').val(),
                            showDeleted: $('#showDeletedEvents').is(':checked'),
                        };
                    }
                },
                selectable         : true,
                selectHelper       : true,
                theme              : false,
                slotDuration       : '00:15:00',
                defaultView        : 'agendaWeek',
                timeFormat         : 'H:mm',
                slotLabelFormat    : 'H:mm',
                editable           : false,
                firstDay           : 1,
                weekMode           : 'liquid',
                weekNumbers        : true,
                weekNumberTitle    : "T: ",
                minTime            : '06:00:00',
                maxTime            : '20:00:00',
                locale             : 'sk',
                scrollTime         : '00:00',
                aspectRatio        : 1.9,
                slotEventOverlap   : false,
                droppable          : true,
                lazyFetching       : false,
                eventAfterAllRender        : function (view, element) {
                    var date = moment(c.fullCalendar('getDate')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


                    $.ajax({
                        url     : '{{ url('calendar/worktime/get/minmaxtime') }}',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data    : {
                            calendar_id : $('#calendarsselect').val(),
                            date        : date
                        },
                        success : function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            if ( data[0] != '23:59:59')
                            {
                                c.fullCalendar('option','minTime',data[0]);

                            }
                            if ( data[1] != '00:00:00')
                            {
                                c.fullCalendar('option','maxTime',data[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            c.fullCalendar(calendarOptions);

        })($('#calendar'));
```

When I take a look in console I fullcalendar is rerendering all information with minTime included. Anybody with similar experience?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's entirely expected because by changing minTime and maxTime you're changing the display area of the calendar. For that reason it must re-draw the whole display, including re-rendering the events, in order to get the screen into the right state. Of course it then triggers eventAfterAllRender again, which starts the whole process again... Perhaps if you explain your overall goal we can think of a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Hi, based on data in database minTime and maxTime is changing based on week. I need to dynamically change mintime and maxTime when user change week this data needs to be loaded by ajax call from database. Is it enough information about what I need?

Comment: Firstly consider whether this is strictly necessary (I personally as a user would find it confusing if the grid kept expanding and contracting every time I changed the date - it would be hard to follow where each time was occurring - if I was looking for things at 11am for instance, its position on the screen would keep changing, and I either might not notice (and assume something was at a different time than it was) or would just find it annoying.

Comment: Secondly, if you decide you _do_ want to do this, then I think you will have to remove the standard default next/prev buttons for changing the date range, and a) implement your own buttons, which set the new minTime/maxTime _before_ actually changing the view, so that the grid can be drawn correctly. They'd have to call the "next" and "prev" methods manually once this was determined. and b) at startup, don't render the calendar at all until you have the right information.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for feed back. I will try to do my own prev next button implementation. This functionality is requested by client so I cannot do anything with it :)

Comment: No problem. Actually you can do something with it - you can try to convince the client it's not going to produce a usable user interface and change their mind with reasoned argument. If you make a good case (and point out it'll save time and money because you won't spend effort writing custom code for it) then they might be convinced...it depends on the people and the situation of course. But it's up to you. Sometimes it's easier to go along with it and let the client figure it out for themselves when they see the finished product :-)